# What is the difference between ''find .'' and ''find /'' on linux command

Tags: linux, ctf, bandit-python

I am solving overthewire bandit. I looked solutions but there is no explanation about it.
For example when i use `find .` find it on bandit 5->6

```
bandit5@bandit:~/inhere$ find . -type f -readable ! -executable -size 1033c
**./maybehere07/.file2**

bandit5@bandit:~/inhere$ cat ./maybehere07/.file2
**DXjZPULLxYr17uwoI01bNLQbtFemEgo7**
```

I used `find .` on bandit6->7 i didn't get any output
in the solution they solved with `find /`

```
bandit6@bandit:~$ find /  -user bandit7 -group bandit6 -size 33c 2>/dev/null
/var/lib/dpkg/info/bandit7.password
```

both of are ASCII Text so what is the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about the linux `find` command:

`find .  [other expressions]` means you want to find files based on your current directory.

While `find / [other expressions]` means you want to find files based on the root (`/`) directory.

Answer (score 1):

The *path* parameter tells `find` where to search. If you use `.`, it will only search in the subdirectories of the current directory, while `/` means the root directory, i.e. it will search everywhere. And, indeed, as you can see, `/var/lib/dpkg/info/` is not a subdirectory of `~/inhere`.